# Running CLI commands in php

Tags: php, command, command-line-interface

Does anyone know the exact php function to run CLI commands. I have a application that i would like to use that has CLI (command line interface) to use to integrate and would like to run those commands using php.

Is exec the correct function to use? Hope this makes sense

Comment: would testing exec() be so hard?

Comment: would just answering be so hard? Why would u mark this question down?

Comment: due to lack of research effort, you should read the faq before posting

Comment: Testing whether `exec` does the job would've been less work than typing this question actually.

Comment: The reason i didnt try it is because the software i speak of has not been installed yet on the server so i do not really know the commands to run before hand thought id just ask to save time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See the Program Execution Functions reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php).

You can use `exec`, `passthru` and `system`, or for more complex scenarios `shell_exec` or `proc_open`. For a simple CLI automation task `exec` will do just fine.

Comment: What would be the benefit of using one over the other?

Comment: There are minor differences in the way they handle return output - `passthru` echoes it, the other 2 return it, etc. You should just read the documentation though, or use `exec` as it's usually the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use PHP's exec() function to execute external commands:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php